# Regex algorithm to filter complex strings

Tags: javascript, sql, regex

Consider this SQL string (Invalid SQL)

```
SELECT * FROM venue AS v, date AS d 
WHERE "v"."venueId" = '1' 
AND "v"."<PREFIX>d.dateId" = '102' 
AND "v"."<PREFIX>d.dateTime" = '12345678'
LIMIT 5;
```

How can we fix the invalid SQL by transforming e.g.
`"v"."<PREFIX>d.dateId"` into `"d.dateId"`

- `"v"."<PREFIX>` was removed
- An unique PREFIX can be inserted above (example) to help with the filtering

Expected valid SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM venue AS v, date AS d
WHERE "v"."venueId" = '1' 
AND "d"."dateId" = '102' 
AND "d"."dateTime" = '12345678'
LIMIT 5;
```

Or alternative valid SQL (without double quotes for column `alias.columnName` in WHERE conditions)

```
SELECT * FROM venue AS v, date AS d 
WHERE v.venueId = '1' 
AND d.dateId = '102' 
AND d.dateTime = '12345678'
LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: *An unique PREFIX was inserted to help with the filtering* - and what is that prefx?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest any prefix of your choice can be inserted at the <PREFIX> spot. Thank you for clarifying, I have updated the question to reflect this better

Comment: have you already try any regex matching?

Comment: Why not fix the SQL at the source that generated this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to have that prefix as the match concerns a second pair of quotes that includes a point:

```js
const badsql = `SELECT * FROM venue AS v, date AS d 
WHERE "v"."venueId" = '1' 
AND "v"."d.dateId" = '102' 
AND "v"."d.dateTime" = '12345678'
LIMIT 5;`;

const sql = badsql.replace(/"[^"]+"\.("[^."]+)\./g, '$1"."');

console.log(sql);
```